# Is there a general template for turning an applet into a shell program?

Tags: java, command-line

Sorry if I haven't asked this in a way people can understand. I have source code for someone's Java applet, and I want to be able to run it from the shell in scripts. The person said I should be able to strip it down and call it from the shell. But what does this require? Does it require using a certain library (for cflags, etc?)? Just a rough answer will do, thanks.

Comment: Do you have the source or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.woodger.ca/jv_appst.htm

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/TurningAnApplet/

Comment: Sadly, the second link doesn't go to the right place any more.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the official answer: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/TurningAnApplet/.

Answer (score 1):

In principle you can invoke your applet in the `appletviewer` (this is a program contained in your JRE), which is callable from a shellscript, too. It does not return usable values to your script, though.

The general way would be to add a main method to your Applet, which creates a Frame (or JFrame) and puts the applet inside it. Hope the applet doesn't call much applet-specific methods, since they won't work (if you don't implement and supply an own AppletStub).